# What is the protocol for sending files over SSH, in code?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I was reading some Go code that sends a file over an SSH client.

https://github.com/tmc/scp/blob/master/scp.go#L33

One of the things it does is a `scp -t /remote/path`. What is that `-t` flag for? I did a `man scp`, but it doesn't seem to be documented. I ran the command locally and it seems to behave like cat.

After running `scp -t` remotely, the code then sends bytes to the server like this.

```go
// Some special control header? What is this?
fmt.Fprintf(w, "C%#o %d %s\n", mode, size, fileName)
// Send file bytes.
io.Copy(w, contents)
// Send termination signal?
fmt.Fprint(w, "\x00")
```

What is this protocol? Is it documented anywhere?

Comment: scp's `-t`, `-f` and `-d` options are not documented because they're not user-serviceable; they're only used when starting the "server" scp on the remote machine.

Comment: [How the SCP protocol works](https://web.archive.org/web/20170215184048/https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, the scp protocol isn't documented anywhere else than it the source code of [`scp.c`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/scp.c), so here is an attempt to an outline of how `scp` works.

When either the source or the destination is a remote machine, `scp` will use `ssh` to connect and start a `scp` program on it: if the copy direction is from the remote to the local, it will be started as `scp -f src` (**from / source**), otherwise it will be started as `scp -t dst` (**to / sink**), and the local `scp` will assume the opposite posture.

After this the two scp processes are running on both ends of the scp connection, using it as their stdin/stdout and passing the file data and metadata over it.

Both ends could use the following responses to acknowledge messages or signal some error condition:

1. `"\0"`: OK
2. `"\1%s\n", err_msg`: non-fatal error
3. `"\2%s\n", err_msg`: fatal error

The transfer starts by the **to / sink scp** sending a `\0` (OK) ack.

Then the **from / source scp** will use the following messages:

1. `"C%04o %lld %s\n", mode, size, filename`: create a file

   this is followed by `size` bytes of file data, and an ack (`\0` = OK)
2. `"D%04o 0 %.1024s\n", mode, dirname`: start of directory

   recursively followed by `C`, `D` or `T` messages, until a
3. `"E\n"`: end of directory
4. `"T%llu 0 %llu 0\n", mtime, atime`: file times

   this is sent before the `C` or `D` messages, if the `-p` switch was used.

These messages will have to be ack'ed by the other side before proceding further, including the `C` before sending the file data, and the ack sent after it.

In the `C` and `D` messages above, newlines and other control chars (except `\t` and `\x7f`) in the file/dir name will be escaped as eg. `\^J`, but will **not** be unescaped at the destination; a literal `\^J` or `\^M` in the original name will be left as-is.

The difference between fatal and non-fatal errors is not consistent; only `\1` (non-fatal) errors will be generated by either side, but some of them will be considered fatal, and `scp` will exit upon sending or receiving them, leaving the other side to hold both pieces. Both sides will exit upon a `\2` (fatal) error or anything unexpected.

Unlike in http, there are no provisions for sending the file data by chunks; if the source `scp` is no longer able to read some big file it has started sending after the `C` message, it will send up to its `size` NUL bytes before the `\1` error message / nak.

Comment: Correct. Just worth mentioning, that the local side does not have to be the `scp` (and does not have to use the `ssh`). It can be another implementation of the SCP protocol. Actually, like in case of OP, where the Go code implements the local-side-`scp`. While the remote side will indeed almost always be the OpenSSH `scp` (or at least has to believe like it and be named `scp`). See [Explanation for SCP protocol implementation in JSch library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26220381/850848).